# How to use cell content as a reference in offset formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell content as `"$k$7"` in `'T7'` cell, how do I use the `'T7'` cell content as a reference pointer in offset formula.
just like `=Offset (**T7 Cell content**, 1,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=OFFSET(INDIRECT($T$7),1,0)`

Comment: I think you meant `INDIRECT(T7)` :)

Comment: =OFFSET(INDIRECT($K$7),1,0)
Here i need to know how we can read T7 cell content using formula. instead of directly replacing '$K$7'

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you @Rory

Comment: @KarthikPB Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @JoeJam - Yes correct, thank you.
Its working fine now :)